# Cannot convert value of type '(String) -> Void' to expected argument type '((AnyObject!) -> Void)!'

Tags: swift, uiimageview, completionhandler, anyobject

I am trying to capture image by tap on captureDoc button. But when I wrote this function suddenly I got the above stated error in the completion handler,

```
 self.scanDoc.captureImageWithCompletionHander({(imageFilePath: String) -> Void in
```

And I am not getting what went wrong.
Below is my code of captureDoc function.

```
@IBAction func captureDoc(sender: AnyObject) {
    weak var weakSelf = self
            self.scanDoc.captureImageWithCompletionHander({(imageFilePath: String) -> Void in
                var captureImageView: UIImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage.imageWithContentsOfFile(imageFilePath)!)
                captureImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha: 0.7)
                captureImageView.frame = CGRectOffset(weakSelf.view.bounds, 0, -weakSelf.view.bounds.size.height)
                captureImageView.alpha = 1.0
                captureImageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
                captureImageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
                weakSelf.view!.addSubview(captureImageView)
                var dismissTap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: weakSelf, action: #selector(self.dismissPreview))
                captureImageView.addGestureRecognizer(dismissTap)
                UIView.animateWithDuration(0.7, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0.7, options: .AllowUserInteraction, animations: {() -> Void in
                    captureImageView.frame = weakSelf.view.bounds
                })

            })

}
```

Comment: Make it just `imageFilePath` instead of `(imageFilePath: String) -> Void`.

Comment: When I did what you said its give me an error on next line the error is  'AnyObject!' is not convertible to 'String'; did you mean to use 'as!' to force downcast? on the 4th line where I declared a captureImageView  and when I downcast it to String then it show me an another error of 'imageWithContentsOfFile' is unavailable: use object construction 'UIImage(contentsOfFile:)'  @Dershowitz123

Answer (score 0):

change the last line, it should work

```
@IBAction func captureDoc(_ sender: UIButton) {
weak var weakSelf = self
        self.scanDoc.captureImageWithCompletionHander({(imageFilePath: String?) -> Void in
            var captureImageView: UIImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage.imageWithContentsOfFile(imageFilePath!)!)
            captureImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha: 0.7)
            captureImageView.frame = CGRectOffset(weakSelf.view.bounds, 0, -weakSelf.view.bounds.size.height)
            captureImageView.alpha = 1.0
            captureImageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
            captureImageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
            weakSelf.view!.addSubview(captureImageView)
            var dismissTap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: weakSelf, action: #selector(self.dismissPreview))
            captureImageView.addGestureRecognizer(dismissTap)
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.7, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0.7, options: .AllowUserInteraction, animations: {() -> Void in
                captureImageView.frame = weakSelf.view.bounds
            }, completion: { _ in })

        })
```

}